# Rails: set file to file_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, file-upload, filefield

Having the following form:

```
= form_for company, html: { multipart: true } do |form|
    = form.label :logo, 'Upload Image'
    = form.file_field :logo
```

I want to set file_field value to another user uploaded image (have the object of `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` class). Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the value for the file field and its because of security.

e.g 
would you want websites on the internet to be able to automatically set a value of `C:/some_secret_folder/password.txt` to a file field and submit the form through JS ?